# Fat band using matplotlib in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, physics, thickness

I would like to plot a line with varying thickness using matplotlib in python.

To be clearer, I have the following variable

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as P 
import numpy as N

x_value = N.arange(0,10,1)
y_value = N.random.rand(10)
bandwidth = N.random.rand(10)*10
P.plot(x_value,y_value,bandwidth)
```

I would like to plot a line with x_value and y_value and a thickness that vary with the x_value position and given by the bandwidth vector.

A possible solution that I see would be to draw the upper and lower line (i.e. I take y_value[index] +- bandwidth[index]/2 and plot those two lines.

Then I could try to fill the space between the two lines (how?)

If you have any suggestions?

Thank you,

Samuel.

Comment: I think this is a repeat.  Does this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390895/matplotlib-plot-with-variable-line-width not do what you want?

Comment: @DailRowe: not sure what the OP wants specifically, but a line with variable thickness is different than a variable width band because the line width specifies the width perpendicular to the line, while a band width is specified along the y-axis so its width could be read from the y-values (at least as I've done here).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using [`fill_between`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between).

For example, to have half the `bandwidth` above and half below (and also drawing the original line using `plot`):

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as P 
import numpy as N

x_value = N.arange(0,10,1)
y_value = N.random.rand(10)
bandwidth = N.random.rand(10)*10
print bandwidth
P.fill_between(x_value, y_value+bandwidth/2, y_value-bandwidth/2, alpha=.5)
P.plot(x_value,y_value)
P.show()
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. As you mention I need an absolute width and not a width perpendicular to the line !