# How to adjust the line width to different values for a line chart in Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, linechart, linewidth

I am trying to create a line chart with Matplotlib in Python. Is there a way to adjust the width of the line based on different values? That means for one line, its width is different for different values on x axis. The example chart I am trying to create is shown here:

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390895/matplotlib-plot-with-variable-line-width) answers your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib plot with variable line width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390895/matplotlib-plot-with-variable-line-width)

Comment: Thanks, Andrea and gboffi. The above link is really helpful.