# matplotlib pandas: Change width between datapoints based on another columns value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

Tried my best to bring it in one picture:

[image: matplotlib-set-width-based-on-column]

I would like to increase the `width` of such lines between two datapoints which have a higher `z` value. Painting them red when they go over a certain threshold would be nice..

1. Is that possible with matplotlib?
2. Or with an alternative libary which works on `pd.DataFrame()`?
3. Are there certain limits to keep in mind when ploting this way with bigger datasets?

---

Example mock up:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(minutes=1), freq='s')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
y = np.random.randint(10, high=13, size=len(days))
z = np.random.randint(1, high=10, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': days, 'y': y, 'z': z})
df = df.set_index('ts')
print(df)

df.y.plot()
```

Comment: don't post pictures. post code and data

Comment: Dear @PaulH, yes, well that is true and I could write some simple code  [how to change a simple line style](https://www.pythoninformer.com/python-libraries/matplotlib/line-plots/) like `.plot([..], color='red', linewidth=10)`. Sadly, these interfaces look not suitable, because I am looking for a point-by-point approach to integrate information from an additional column into the line. And for me that picture points to the target picture very easy.

Comment: I'm saying people should be able to copy-paste some code to generate your data and what you've already tried. you can do this in seaborn, but i'm not going to mock up a dataset for you

Comment: @PaulH There you go - Added example mockup to generate dataset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another approach, based on using a `LineCollection` like in this [example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, date2num, SecondLocator

date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(minutes=1), freq='s')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
y = np.random.randint(10, high=13, size=len(days))
z = np.random.randint(1, high=10, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': days, 'y': y, 'z': z})
df = df.set_index('ts')

# Make each line segment
points = np.array([date2num(df.index), y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

# Make the line collection, setting the default line color to red if z > 5
# otherwise blue, and linewidth to 2 if z >= previous value, otherwise 1
lc = LineCollection(
    segments,
    color=np.where(z > 5, 'red', 'blue'),
    linewidth=np.where(z[1:] >= z[:-1], 2, 1),
)

# Add it to the plot and auto scale axes to take lines into account
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()

# Format the x-axis nicely
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(SecondLocator(range(0, 60, 10)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
plt.show()
```

This gives the following plot
[image]

Comment: Why have you chosen to select  `color` via `z > 0.25` but `linewidth` with `np.where(z[1:] >= z[:-1], 5, 1)`?

Comment: @Asmus it is just an example based on how I interpreted the question (I may be wrong so the OP should correct me if so). I think the question is clear that the line width should be thicker if the z value is higher than the previous. It wasn't clear to me whether the "threshold" is the same criterion or a different one.

Comment: Ah, I see. Anyway, I like your solution, have an upvote! :)

Comment: @tomjn Thanks for your answer - It looks promessing. Regarding your comment: You are right with the assumption that the line should be bigger based on `z` (without any threshold). The `threshold` criteria is only for *ploting the line-segment in a different color*, if `z>threshold`. So it is all correct here :)

Comment: Finally found the time to apply your approach. It works like expected - Thanks! Maybe it is worth mentioned, that if you come from a `pd.DataFrame` already, you can go like `y = df['y'].to_numpy()`. The rest is straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would do it: basically I'm adding conditional rows (`df'[linewidth]', df['linecolors']`) to the dataframe, which hold the plot options for plotting line segments, and plot the data as line segments (i.e. not a continous line), based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30563946/565489) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390895/matplotlib-plot-with-variable-line-width)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(minutes=1), freq='s')

# np.random.seed(seed=1111)
# y = np.random.randint(10, high=13, size=len(days))
# z = np.random.randint(1, high=10, size=len(days))

## note that I'm using a cosine function here instead, 
#  in order to make it easier to see that the code is working
y = np.cos(np.linspace(0,4*np.pi,len(days)))
z = y

df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': days, 'y': y, 'z': z})
df = df.set_index('ts')

## create new columns to hold the linewidths and associated colors, depending on a threshold value
threshold = -.25
thick_linewidth = 5
thin_linewidth = 1
thick_color = "r"
thin_color = "b"

df['threshold_bool']  =  np.where(df['z']>= threshold, 1, 0) ### only for debug, you don't really need this
df['linewidth'] =  np.where(df['z']>= threshold, thick_linewidth, thin_linewidth)
df['linecolors'] =  np.where(df['z']>= threshold, thick_color, thin_color)

def plot_widths(xs, ys, widths, colors, ax=None, xlim=None, ylim=None,
                **kwargs):
    if not (len(xs) == len(ys) == len(widths)):
        raise ValueError('xs, ys, and widths must have identical lengths')
    fig = None
    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

    segmentx, segmenty = [xs[0]], [ys[0]]
    current_width = widths[0]
    color = colors[0]
    
    ## to debug the visualisation use:
    ax.scatter(xs.values,ys.values,edgecolors="k",facecolors="w",marker='o',s=12**2,zorder=19)
    for (x,y,z) in zip(xs.values,ys.values,df['threshold_bool'].values):
        ax.text(x,y,z,ha="center",va="center",zorder=20)
    #####
    
    for ii, (x, y, width) in enumerate(zip(xs, ys, widths)):
        segmentx.append(x)
        segmenty.append(y)
        if (width != current_width) or (ii == (len(xs) - 1)):
            
                
            ax.plot(segmentx, segmenty, linewidth=current_width, color=color,
                    **kwargs)
            segmentx, segmenty = [x], [y]
            
            current_width = width
            if width == thick_linewidth:
                color = thick_color
            else:
                color = thin_color
                
    if xlim is None:
        xlim = [min(xs), max(xs)]
    if ylim is None:
        ylim = [min(ys), max(ys)]
    ax.set_xlim(xlim)
    ax.set_ylim(ylim)

    return ax if fig is None else fig

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plot_widths(df.index, df.y, df.linewidth, df.linecolors, ax=ax, )
ax.axhline(threshold,linestyle="dashed",color="r")
plt.show()
```

Which yields:

[image: Variable line widths]

Note that I added scatter points & text via `df['threshold_bool']`, in order to highlight how the code decides whether a segment is above or below the threshold, see comments in the code.

Comment: Uhh that looks very good. Will check that during the next days and report back.